# How to store selected value in Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, dropdown

I have a dropdown and I want to store the selected value in Vuex store:

```
<select name="lang" v-model="lang" @change="setLanguage($event.target.value)">
                    <option key="0" value="en">English</option>
                    <option key="1" value="de">Deutsch</option>
                </select>

setLanguage(selectedLanguage) {
            this.$store.dispatch('setLanguage', {
                language: selectedLanguage,
            })
        }
```

It is my dropdown and whenever the value change, I want to change it in the store also.

So my action in vuex store:

```
export const setLanguage = ({commit}, language) => {
    commit('STORE_LANGUAGE', language);
}
```

mutation:

```
export const STORE_LANGUAGE = (state, language) => {
    state.language = language;
}
```

and state:

```
export default {
    language: "en",
}
```

Comment: And what problem do you have with all this code?

Comment: I am changing the value in dropdown but it doesnt change in the store in real time

Comment: The problem is most likely in your template. Can you add more code there?

Comment: What do you mean `real time`? Did you check it in Vue Tools?

Comment: Did you bind `lang` from model to vuex store?

Answer (score 0):

In action

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-forked-vls9w

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>{{ getLang }}</h2>
    <select v-model="langSelect">
      <option value="en">en</option>
      <option value="tr">tr</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "LangChange",
  data() {
    return {
      langSelect: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    getLang () {
      return this.$store.getters.getLanguage;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    langSelect: function (val, oldVal) {
      this.$store.dispatch("setLanguage", val);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = {
  lang: ""
};

const mutations = {
  STORE_LANGUAGE(state, payload) {
    state.lang = payload;
  }
};

const actions = {
  setLanguage(context, number) {
    context.commit("STORE_LANGUAGE", number);
  }
};

const getters = {
  getLanguage(state) {
    return state.lang;
  }
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
});
```